# user-defined exceptions with enumeration "error level"

Tags: c#, exception, enums, enumeration, user-defined

I have made some user-defined exceptions and I would like to add an error level to each exception. forexample userInputerror, and internalError. The reason I'm coding this, is because I want to learn about exceptions so that's why I am reinventing the wheel instead of using log4net.

My code looks like this.

I have a class called MyException:

```
namespace ExceptionHandling
{
    public class MyException : ApplicationException
    {
        public MyException(string message)
            : base(message)
        { 

        }

        public MyException(string message, Exception innerException)
            : base(message, innerException)
        { 

        }
    }
}
```

One of my exceptions is an IntParseException, this class looks like this:

```
namespace ExceptionTester
{
    class IntParseException : MyException
    {
    string dataToParse;

    public IntParseException(string dataToParse)
        : base(" [ERROR] Could not parse " + dataToParse + " to int")
    {
        this.dataToParse = dataToParse;

    }

    public IntParseException(string dataToParse, Exception innerexception) 
        : base(" [ERROR] Could not parse " + dataToParse + " to int", innerexception)
    {
        this.dataToParse = dataToParse;           
    }
}
```

}

In my mainform, I am handling my exception like this:

```
    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            try
            {
                int.Parse(txtNumber.Text);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {  
                throw new IntParseException(txtNumber.Text, ex);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogWriter lw = new LogWriter(ex.Source, ex.TargetSite.ToString(), ex.Message);
            logwindow.upDateLogWindow();
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number");                          
        }
    }
```

I'm logging my exceptions and that class looks liked this:

```
namespace ExceptionTester
{
    class LogWriter
    {
        public LogWriter(string exSource, string exTargetSite, string exMessage)
        {
            StreamWriter SW;
            SW = File.AppendText(@"logfile.txt");
            string timeStamp = "[" + DateTime.Now + "] ";
            string source = "An error occured in the application ";
            string targetSite = ", while executing the method: ";
            SW.WriteLine(timeStamp + source + exSource + targetSite +exTargetSite + exMessage);
            SW.Flush();
            SW.Close();
        }

    }
}
```

So my question is, how do I add an enum type to my exceptions which would make it possible for me to chose which kinds of exceptions I want to log. forexample, at somepoint I would like to log all exceptions but at another time I only want to log userInputErrors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest creating a new base exception class inheriting from Application Exception, which include the enum:s

```
public enum ErrorLevel { UserInputError, DatabaseError, OtherError... };

public class BaseException : ApplicationException {
  protected ErrorLevel _errorLevel;
  ...
}
```

Derive all your exception from this base class, and assign the level as needed - maybe in the constructors, or using a parameter passed from the app.

Answer (score 3):

BTW, Microsoft no longer recommends that you derive from `ApplicationException`. Derive directly from `Exception`, instead.

Also, in your logging, be certain to log the entire exception. Use ex.ToString(), not ex.Message, etc. This will guarantee you see everything the exception class wants you to see, including all inner exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just trying to log certain exceptions, why not just make that decision based on what type of exception is thrown, and forego this reinvention of the wheel as you call it?

```
try
{
    // do stuff that might throw exception
}
catch(ExceptionType1 ex1)
{
    // Ignore
}
catch(ExceptionType2 ex2)
{
    // Log
}
```

However, it would be trivial to add an enum to your custom exception, though I DO NOT CONDONE THIS HORSE HOCKEY!

```
enum ExceptionLevel
{
    One, Two, Three
}

class MyException : ApplicationException
{
    ExceptionLevel ExceptionLevel;
}
```

Comment: I wan't to be able to change it while running my program. so I don't have to change something in the code. Just thought that enum could be used to something like that, but I'm just not sure how to do it.

Comment: I would say as a general guideline that what you're proposing is a bad design decision. I mean, exception handling is by very nature a "real-time" thing. I just can't see any benefit to this exception handling paradigm.

Comment: And you can still accomplish "changing" which exceptions to handle based on type. An enum is just unnecessary "cruftness".

Comment: #Eric - I read his question to say that he wanted to contol his exception *logging*, not modify his exception *handling*. To me, the enum idea seems like a nice way to handle this.